# Example of $∫_\Omega|f|^p$ uniformly bounded for $p<p_0$ but $∫_\Omega|f|^{p_0}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I am seeking for an example of function $f$ that for $p<p_0$, $\int_\Omega|f|^p<M$ are uniformly bounded, but $\int_\Omega|f|^{p_0}=\infty$.

Here $\Omega$ is finite.

I tried the most usual example $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^s}$ for $s\rightarrow1^-$ but $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^s}=\frac{1}{1-s}$ is not bounded.

Comment: See Fatou's lemma; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma. You can drop the assumption $\lvert\Omega\rvert<\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such example exists. Since $\Omega$ is finite (measure), we may restrict attention to the set where $|f| > 1$. On this set, $|f|^p$ increases to $|f|^{p_0}$ pointwise as $p \uparrow p_0$. So by monotone convergence theorem, the integrals converge.

Comment: Thanks that's right. What if $p_0=\infty$?

Comment: @P.R I think $||f||_\infty$ has to be at most $1$ in order for $\sup_p \int_\Omega |f|^p$ to be finite (note that you don't have a $p$-th root). Indeed, if there were some $\epsilon > 0$ so that $\{|f| > 1+\epsilon\}$ had positive measure $\mu$, then $\int_\Omega |f|^p \ge (1+\epsilon)^p\mu$.

Comment: @P.R does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I think it is right even with p -th root.